# having problems setting this div width to 1px?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've created the following UI component:

http://codepen.io/ac123/pen/xqYzxR

```
<div id="MapKeys">
    <div id="RegionalSupply">
        <div class="header">Regional supply</div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="detail">Circles sized by the amount of change from the previous period</div>
    </div>
    <div id="CorridorNetFlowDirection">
        <div class="header">Corridor net flow direction</div>
        <div class="dottedLine">
            <div class="part1"></div>
            <div class="part2"></div>
            <div class="part3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail">Lines sized by the amount of change in net flow from the previous period</div>
    </div>
</div>

#MapKeys
{
    .header{
        font-size:16px;
    }

    #RegionalSupply{

        height:100px;
        width:240px;
        border:solid purple 1px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;

        & > .circle {
            width: 14px;
            height: 14px;
            background: lightgrey;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            display:inline-block;
        }

        & > .detail{
            display:inline-block;
            width:150px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    }

    #CorridorNetFlowDirection{

        height:100px;
        width:240px;
        border:solid red 1px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px;

        & > .dottedLine
        {
            & > .part1{
                width: 12px;
                height: 10px;
                background: lightgrey;
                display:inline-block;
            }

            & > .part2{
                width: 1px;
                height: 10px;
                background: none;
                display:inline-block;
            }

            & > .part3{
                width: 12px;
                height: 10px;
                background: lightgrey;
                display:inline-block;
            }
        }

        & > .detail{
            display:inline-block;
            width:150px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    }
}
```

The "Corridor net flow direction" component displays a grey icon which represents a dotted line. I've defined this dotted line as 3 adjacent divs with the middle div having wdith:1px and background:none.

However, the appearance of the rendered middle div width looks more like 6px or 7px. What do I need to adjust in my css or html in order for this dotted line to display a width of 1px between the 1st and 3rd divs?

Also, how can I specify the shared css attrs for part1, part2, part3 in this scenario?  For example, I would expect the following shared styling to work but it doesn't:

```
& > .dottedLine
{
    height: 10px;
    display:inline-block;

    & > .part1{
        width: 12px;
        background: lightgrey;
    }

    & > .part2{
        width: 1px;
        background: none;
    }

    & > .part3{
        width: 12px;
        background: lightgrey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `font-size: 0px;` to the parent container named `.dottedLine`

```
.dottedLine{
font-size:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that 1px distance (without additional space) when you completely avoid/erase any spaces and also line-breaks between the DIVs in the HTML code. So that part of the code would be:

```
<div id="CorridorNetFlowDirection"><div class="header">Corridor net flow direction</div><div class="dottedLine"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div><div class="part3"></div></div><div class="detail">Lines sized by the amount of change in net flow from the previous period</div>
```

See it working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJqaxN

Answer (score 1):

Make it `font-size: 0px;` to the parent container `.dottedLine`

```
.dottedLine{font-size:0px;}
```